# Using the UE4 mannequin for scale in Blender

Tags: scale, units, unreal-engine

So I am rather new to Blender, UE4 and modelling in general and am currently about to create a modular pack to import into UE4 and create a scene. I have done reading on units and scaling in both programs and have made sure I am going to be 1:1 for the process though I am scratching my head with one thing... the mannequin for reference.
I will be creating hallways, walls, doors, windows etc etc and want to make sure they all look and feel right in context. So as far as I can tell in my research, the UE4 mannequin is 183cm tall in UE4, so I am rather confused after exporting it and importing it into Blender that it comes out around 210cm tall in Blender. I thought I was 1:1 where does this 27cm difference come from and what is the way out of this? Oh, and I want precise not approximated size.
I can't find an answer anywhere.

I'm at a loss because I am a noob. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: How do you measure in Blender and UE4?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender you can input math operations instead of values. In your case select the mannequin followed by <kbd>S</kbd> **183/210** This will reduce the size to that you had in UE4.

Putting Scale X,Y and Z transform fields to 183/210 and hitting Enter works as well. Also, this is the way to use with i.a. modifiers and every field.

Comment: Oh brilliant thank you! For some reason pressing s followed by 183/210 didn't work as the / wouldn't input, but doing it in the transform fields worked a treat!